# How to make Org-Babel support tangel to su/sudo file with tramp-sudo?

Tags: org-babel, tramp, sudo

I hope to let org-babel can tangle to root permission file with tramp-sudo support like the following format:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :dir /sudo:: :tangle "/etc/kk.clj"
...
#+END_SRC
```

But it does not work. How to implement this?

Here is the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Removing old name" "Permission denied" "/etc/nginx/conf.d/kk.clj")
  #<subr delete-file>("/etc/nginx/conf.d/kk.clj" nil)
  ad-Advice-delete-file(#<subr delete-file> "/etc/nginx/conf.d/kk.clj")
  apply(ad-Advice-delete-file #<subr delete-file> "/etc/nginx/conf.d/kk.clj")
  delete-file("/etc/nginx/conf.d/kk.clj")
  ...  [assoc 4] 6 "\n\n(fn SPEC NAME)"] :tangle :shebang 0 :tangle-mode "yes" file-name-sans-extension "no" nil "." :mkdirp file-name-directory make-directory parents file-exists-p mapcar car delete-file generate-new-buffer " *temp*" make-byte-code "
  ...
  mapc(....
  org-babel-tangle((4))
  funcall-interactively(org-babel-tangle (4))
  call-interactively(org-babel-tangle nil nil)
  command-execute(org-babel-tangle)
```

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but the language setting `conf` requires loading a package ´ob-conf.el` or something like this. Could you show the complete example and the error message?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I updated my question. Check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prefix tangle file path with `/sudo::`.

```
#+NAME: privoxy config for convert socks5 to HTTP proxy
#+BEGIN_SRC conf :tangle "/sudo::/etc/privoxy/config"
listen-address localhost:8118
forward-socks5 /  127.0.0.1:1080  .
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file name, I believe. `/etc/privoxy/config` is an absolute file name, the `:dir` parameter does not count therefore.

If you use a relative file name, like `:dir "/sudo::/etc/" :tangle "privoxy/config"` it shall work. This is to be preferred, if you have several code blocks applicable to the same directory `/sudo::/etc/` via a global header setting for `:dir`.

Comment: It does not work. If I use `:dir "/sudo::/etc/" :tangle "privoxy/config"`. Then it will tangle to `privoxy/config`.

Comment: Then I suppose `:tangle` does ignore the `:dir` setting. Whether this is a bug or a feature I don't know.